# Creating a table with a primary key and then inserting data into it

Tags: mysql

I executing this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE test_mod SELECT * FROM `test`
```

This copied a table into the newly created table. Then I executed this:

```
INSERT INTO test_mod(`test_name`) SELECT `test_name` FROM test
```

That statement should have inserted more data to the newly created table. It did so, but the primary key are all 0?!?!

The I executed this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE test_mod MODIFY test_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

And phpmyadmin told me that the column test_id has already an auto_increment attribute.. so how can I populate more data while having an auto increment functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
CREATE TABLE test_mod LIKE test;
INSERT INTO test_mod SELECT * FROM test;
```

This will copy the table definition from "test" and insert all data from it into "test_mod".